# Automatically generate subplots based on length of a list

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot

I want to generate colorplot subplots based on a numpy array's length which I call dets. I want to use the array length to determine the right number of columns and rows for the subplots. If square, plot a square matrix of subplots, if not square, add another row. For starters, I have written some code to check if the array's length would create a square matrix of subplots with the following:

```
data_f = np.random.rand(len(dets),2,5)
dets = np.arange(-5,-0.75,0.25)
x = np.array([1,5,6,3,8,9,2,3,10,12,3])
v = np.linspace(0,10,len(x))

square = np.sqrt(len(dets))
check_square = len(dets)%square
non_square = 1

print(len(data_f))

if check_square == 0:
    nrows = int(np.sqrt(len(dets)))
    ncols = int(np.sqrt(len(dets)))
else:
    nrows = int(np.sqrt(len(dets)))+non_square
    ncols = int(np.sqrt(len(dets)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows, ncols, sharex='col', sharey='row')

for i in range(nrows):
    for j in range(ncols):
        if i==0:
            im = ax[i,j].imshow(data_f[j],extent=(x.min(), x.max(), v.min(), v.max()),origin='lower',aspect='auto')
        else:
             im = ax[i,j].imshow(data_f[j+ncols*i],extent=(x.min(), x.max(), v.min(), v.max()),origin='lower',aspect='auto')
```

The output plot:

This plots 17 plots but the resulting plots I cannot adjust because of the error

[image]

This plots everything I want, except it always smushes the plots together in a weird way because of the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\1/ipykernel_4560/3817292743.py in <module>
      6             im = ax[i,j].imshow(data_f[j],extent=(x.min(), x.max(), v.min(), v.max()),origin='lower',aspect='auto')
      7         else:
----> 8              im = ax[i,j].imshow(data_f[j+ncols*i],extent=(x.min(), x.max(), v.min(), v.max()),origin='lower',aspect='auto')
      9 

IndexError: index 17 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 17
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have a total of 20 axes, and when you loop through ncols and nrows, you will get 20 iterations. But len(data_f) is only 17.

at the start of your iteration, add

```
if(j + ncols*i) == len(data_f): 
    break
```

I did this and it stopped the error